# Google Load Balancer and Compute Engine (auto start/stop VM Instances)

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I want to integrate a Load Balancer for vertical Scaling.
As i read, it´s possible to setup the load Balancer that point every User to the next instance.

But i thought about to do (for example) 5 VM Instances.
When the first 100 Users are on Instance, the load Balancer start the next instance and so on and on ...
After x Minutes if a server is unused it will turn off again until the next peak.
(Maybe a Script that creates instances and delete them?)

Is that a possible and common scenario or am i completely wrong?
In all the description everyone say it´s scaleable, but i don´t want to sit next to the Usage Monitor to start and stop instances.

The Keypoint is to reduce server coast in times when it´s "unused" but be able to handle peaks when i´m "out of office".

Comment: This looks like [horizontal scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_and_vertical_scaling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new feature in GCE 'C[ompute Engine Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/)', note that this is a Limited Preview and you need to apply for it.

Comment: great! thanks! didn´t see that before! i will have a look on it!